# CRUD processing with access controls to SQL Server database

Tags: .net, sql-server, ms-access, dbvisualizer

We have built a large database model (SQL Server) for our client and an automated way to load the data into something like 100 database tables.  Unfortunately due to time constraints (isn't this always the case?) we need to have some capability to offer the client to have access (CRUD access) to these tables for about 20 users.  In addition this access needs to be controlled.  We have an app that's already running at the client (web app C#/.NET) and would rather have something "behind" that.  In the longer term we would build UI screens, but for now they just need some access to the data.

I have thought of a few ideas but I'm looking for other ideas in terms of software or architecture to achieve this:

1. Use MS Access and have it connect directly to SQL Server and create 20 or so users in the database and set them up with MS Access locally.   The cons:  They don't like desktops having direct access to these databases and prefer a web solution.  Also the 20 users are dispersed and getting this done seems more difficult for them.
2. Same as #1 except use something like DB Visualizer.
3. Find some MS Access or DBVisualizer like control to put behind our login page (we have authentication set up on an internal IIS Server and they prefer to use this)...but does these "controls" actually exist that I can plug in to a C#/.NET app?
4. Using scaffolding generate everything.  Haven't done this and I assume this still will take some work and probably be throwaway in the end since the long term goal is building "real" UI pages.

I'm open to any ideas.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Consider http://www.mylittleadmin.com/ a web-based version of SQL Management Studio.  You can use it in combination with standard SQL Server security to customize exactly who can do what.

Comment: Can I put it "behind" my web server which uses .NET membership database authentication?

Comment: No, it'll only work with SQL Server security.

Comment: Wrong. It can work with Windows Authentication as soon as you configure it with impersonation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ASP.NET Dynamic Data](http://www.asp.net/dynamicdata) may be exactly what you're looking for. It's a scaffolding solution and would get something basic up and running very quickly. I'd suggest giving it a look.

Additionally, there's a [CodePlex release](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/14473) that includes a sample of using Dynamic Data with forms auth. See the section titled "Secure Dynamic Data".

Comment: I had seen that but I'm wondering if that's the best solution.  Is it really going to take just a few hours to generate all of this and tie everything together in my site?  Since I have the auth already I just need to generate the pages, but I'm still questioning whether this is easier than finding some control that can sit behind my login.  Nonetheless I'll check your answer, but I would be interested in hearing about experience using this for 100 or so tables.

Comment: @Arthur To be honest, I haven't used it on that scale. I think we used it with about 20-25 tables and a small group of users -- maybe five or six users. It was extremely easy to set up. I think the wizard took less than a minute to run. Customizing a few of the pages and controls was a little slower, but from what I understand that aspect of it has been considerably improved in recent updates.

Answer (score 0):

So you are trying to get people access directly to the data for reports or something to that effect?  You could look at [SQL Reporting Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159106.aspx). I believe it will run as an IIS instance which you can restrict access to.

Comment: Yes, for reports, but importantly for CRUD (viewing, editing) processing on the data similar to what MS Access or DB Visualizer can offer.  My preference is to have something authenticated via our current web server (C#/IIS) module so that they can log in a view some page that really is this tool (like SQL Reporting Services if that gives me what I want).